# How to extract segments of dataframe contains at least two records

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given a dataframe df

```
Trip_id   Latitude   Longitude  Acceleration    date_time    Transportation_Mode  
   1    39.98528333 116.3073667 186.6302183   5/26/2007 10:21       Walk   
   1    39.98521667 116.30955   20.69027793   5/26/2007 10:22       Walk   
   1    39.98513333 116.3097667 12.41329907   5/26/2007 10:22       Walk   
   1    39.9845     116.31      35.69170853   5/26/2007 10:25       Bike  
   1    39.98423333 116.3102333 28.01721471   5/26/2007 10:25       Bike  
   1    39.98403333 116.3104333 2921.070572   5/26/2007 10:25       Bike  
   1    39.98518333 116.3446    197.9064152   5/26/2007 10:29       Bike  
   1    39.96858333 116.3471167 409.3939156   5/26/2007 10:31       Walk   
   1    39.9649     116.3473333 174.0008214   5/26/2007 10:31       Walk   
   1    39.96335    116.3470333 500.6336985   5/26/2007 10:32       Walk   
   1    39.95885    116.3474    298.458933    5/26/2007 10:32       Car  
   1    39.95635    116.3486833 1445.861393   5/26/2007 10:32       Car  
   1    39.94336667 116.3499833 116.5939123   5/26/2007 10:34       Car  
   2    39.94231667 116.3499667 133.0986026   5/26/2007 10:34       Walk   
   2    39.94123333 116.3493    1503.18099    5/26/2007 10:34       Walk   
   2    39.9277     116.3497667 12.37086539   5/26/2007 10:36       Car  
   2    39.91055    116.35045   7.897042746   5/26/2007 10:38       Car
```

I want to achieve the resultant dataframe df1

```
Trip_id Segid   Transportation_Mode  Start_date_time     End_date_time   Mean_Acceleration  Top_Acceleration1   Top_Acceleration2 
   1       1           Walk          5/26/2007 10:21    5/26/2007 10:22  73.24459843          186.6302183        20.69027793  
   1       2           Bike          5/26/2007 10:25    5/26/2007 10:29  795.6714775          2921.070572        197.9064152  
   1       3           Walk          5/26/2007 10:31    5/26/2007 10:32  361.3428118          500.6336985        409.3939156  
   1       4           Car           5/26/2007 10:32    5/26/2007 10:34  620.3047461          1445.861393        298.458933  
   2       1           Walk          5/26/2007 10:34    5/26/2007 10:34  818.1397964          1503.18099         133.0986026  
   2       2           Car           5/26/2007 10:36    5/26/2007 10:38  10.13395407          12.37086539        7.897042746
```

**i)** Group dataframe such that consecutive Transportation_Mode is one group/segment.
**ii)** df1 is list of segments, each segment contains start_date_time and end_date_time of each segment, Mean Acceleration and top 2 accelerations of each segment.
**iii)** A trip is composed of multiple segments and each segment containing one transportation mode.

Comment: I have improved my questions to the best of my efforts. Can anyone guide me how to improve my question. If you think it is easy to understand then upvote please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) by custom functions, only necessary at least 2 values per groups for get top2 of `acceleration`:

```
#convert column to datetimes
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'])

#create helper column for consecutive segment
s = df['Transportation_Mode'].ne(df['Transportation_Mode'].shift()).cumsum().rename('g')

#remove all non duplicated rows per segment
df = df[s.duplicated(keep=False)]

#get top1 and top2 values
f1 = lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False).iloc[0]
f1.__name__ = 'Top_1'
f2 = lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False).iloc[1]
f2.__name__ = 'Top_2'

d = {'date_time':['first','last'], 'Acceleration':['mean', f1, f2]}

df1 = df.groupby(['Trip_id','Transportation_Mode',s], sort=False).agg(d)
#flatenning MultiIndex in columns
df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join)
#MultiIndex in index to columns
df1 = df1.reset_index(level=2, drop=True).reset_index()
```

---

```
print (df1)
   Trip_id Transportation_Mode     date_time_first      date_time_last  \
0        1                Walk 2017-05-26 10:21:00 2017-05-26 10:22:00   
1        1                Bike 2017-05-26 10:25:00 2017-05-26 10:29:00   
2        1                Walk 2017-05-26 10:31:00 2017-05-26 10:32:00   
3        1                 Car 2017-05-26 10:32:00 2017-05-26 10:34:00   
4        2                Walk 2017-05-26 10:34:00 2017-05-26 10:34:00   
5        2                 Car 2017-05-26 10:36:00 2017-05-26 10:38:00   

   Acceleration_mean  Acceleration_Top_1  Acceleration_Top_2  
0          73.244598          186.630218           20.690278  
1         795.671478         2921.070572          197.906415  
2         361.342812          500.633699          409.393916  
3         620.304746         1445.861393          298.458933  
4         818.139796         1503.180990          133.098603  
5          10.133954           12.370865            7.897043
```

Comment: I did't understand your logic. The resultant dataframe is the new dataframe. perhaps you try to merge the results with original dataframe?

Comment: @AsifKhan - In question is `I want to achieve...`, so need something different?

Comment: I rename output DataFrame to `df1`, it is what you need?

Comment: no exactly same thing, but I am getting following error, IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: It means there are no 2 rows for some group, so not possible generate top2. Give me a sec, answer will be edited.

Comment: @AsifKhan - Solution was changed, [5 minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51174449/revisions)

Comment: it works. thanks. one more question,  what change I have to do here to ignore the groups that do not have minimum 2 rows instead of putting NaN.

Comment: @AsifKhan - Remove duplicates by `s`, so use `df = df[s.duplicated(keep=False)]` after `s = df['Transportation_Mode'].ne(df['Transportation_Mode'].shift()).cumsum().rename('g')
`

Comment: I mean ignore those groups having only one row. so don't need statement, if len(x) > 1 else np.nan

Comment: but this is giving an error, IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: Hmmm, maybe real data problem, I suggest use more general solution `df = df[df[['Trip_id','Transportation_Mode']].assign(a=s).duplicated(keep=False)]`

Comment: I need a little extension to this problem. Now I wanted top 3 accelerations in each group and ignore those groups that do not contains at least 3 rows. 
I am able to get 3rd function for acceleration and and got the value but don't know what modification should I do in the code to ignore the groups not containing minimum 3 rows .